# Name masking in R function - Advanced R by Hadley

Tags: r, function

I came across this example in Advanced R by Hadley. My question is after defining the function, j(1) outputs the inner function definition as supposed to what j(1)() is outputting? Intuitively, I think j(1) should output `[1] 1 2`

Could anyone explain what's going on actually? What's the difference between j(1) and j(1)() ?

```
> j <- function(x) {
+   y <- 2
+   function() {
+     c(x,y)
+   }
+ }

> k <- j(1)

> k()
[1] 1 2

> j(1)
function() {
    c(x,y)
  }
<environment: 0x7fa184353bf8>

> j()
function() {
    c(x,y)
  }
<environment: 0x7fa18b5ad0d0>

> j(1)()
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr** In R, the return value of a function can also be a function.  That's the case here. `j(1)` returns a function, whereas `j(1)()` returns a numeric vector.

---

The difference between `j(1)` and `j(1)()` is that `j(1)` outputs a function because that's the last value in the definition of `j`. Functions return their last expression (or the value found in a relevant `return()` call), which in this case is also a function. `j(1)()` is calling the last value of `j`, which is the function returned from it. It does not take an argument, so the empty parentheses `()` is the argument list for `j(1)`

It might become a bit more clear if we have a closer look at `j` and some of its properties.

```
j <- function(x) {
    y <- 2
    function() {
        c(x, y)
    }
}
```

The difference between the calls becomes quite apparent when we look at their classes.

```
class(j(1))
# [1] "function"
class(j(1)())
# [1] "numeric"
```

When you defined `j`, 2 is hard-coded into its return function as the second value of the vector returned from *that* function.  We can see the precise return value of a call to `j(1)` with

```
library(pryr)
unenclose(j(1))
# function () 
# {
#     c(1, 2)
# }
```

So a call to `j(1)()` (or `k()`) will deliver the vector `c(1, 2)`.  Similarly, if we call `j(5)`, the return value of `j(5)()` is `c(5, 2)`

```
unenclose(j(5))
# function () 
# {
#     c(5, 2)
# }
```

Hope that helps.

Credit to @Khashaa for mentioning the `unenclose()` function (comment deleted).